# How to Join Multiple tables in Sql server from Multiple Servers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi i wanted to join two tables which are located on different Sql servers, so how to Join Multiple tables which is having common id's in both tables in Sql server from Multiple Servers

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood your question correctly , the following will help you

```
select *
from [server1].[database1].[dbo].[table1] A
join [server2].[database2].[dbo].[table2] B
on A.id = B.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating linked server to other sql servers.
Go through this URL for further information on linked servers.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ff772782(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ff772782%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Then you can write a single select query to get data from tables of different database of different servers.